# Access reports that the databases are "inconsistent"

Tags: database, ms-access

Yesterday I divided my database into two parts - they are located on the network drive - (frontend and backend) - I did it using the built-in Access option. Backend I hid in a file that only I have access to, and the frontend I made available to some testers (they didn't try to change anything yesterday, only today I informed them about it). All links from the frontend are correct, they lead to my backend. However, today before sharing the database with testers I received such a message (when opening the frontend database): Microsoft Access has detected that the database is inconsistent and will attempt to recover it. During this process, the database will be backed up and all objects will be placed in a new database. Access will then open the new database. Object names that fail to be recovered will be registered in the Recovery Errors table. I found information on Microsoft's website that they know about the problem, but generally nothing adds to my situation. Is there any way to do that, or do we have to wait for them to fix it? The link mentioned above is: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-reports-that-databases-are-in-an-inconsistent-state-%EF%BB%BF-7ec975da-f7a9-4414-a306-d3a7c422dc1d.

Comment: What do you mean by only you have access to a file - do you mean a folder? All users must have permission to read/write that folder.

Comment: have two folders: one with a backend and the other with a frontend. The backend is accessible only to me, there are tables. Users have access to the frontend - they have full rights there, in addition, I will add that the frontend has correctly configured connections with the backend (updated links).

Generally my problem is that yesterday it worked for me and my colleague, and today a colleague tried to open this database to check (front) and there was a message shown in the main post.

Comment: You shouldn't put your frontend on a network. You should provide each user with a local frontend.

Comment: @Rene What if there are 20 users of my application (I don't know exactly how many will be final, at the moment it is about 10 people, but at the end there may be more of them). For example, if I change something in the form (I'll add a button) I have to "send" a new version of the form to 20 users?

Comment: @Jakub, correct, you'll have to provide all of them with a new version. Gustav showed you how you could do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, if I change something in the form (I'll add a button) I
>   have to "send" a new version of the form to 20 users?

Yes you will. But I wrote an article about how to carry this out smoothly using a shortcut and a script:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html)

If you have no account, browse to the link: *Read the full article*

The script:

```
Option Explicit

' Launch script for a Microsoft Access application.
' Version 2.0.2
' 2019-01-15
' Cactus Data. Gustav Brock

' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' This script file must be placed in a distribution folder, like:
'   F:\Distribution\AppName
'
' That folder must have subfolder(s) for the app type(s).
' - for one app type only, for example:
'   F:\Distribution\AppName\Files
' - for, say, three app types:
'   F:\Distribution\AppName\Operations
'   F:\Distribution\AppName\Test
'   F:\Distribution\AppName\Development
'
' Specify the next constants for a resulting install path of:
'   %LocalAppData%\OrgSubfolderName\AppSubfolderName\AppTypeSubfolderName
' - for example resulting in:
'   C:\Users\UserProfileName\AppData\Local\Organisation\AppName\Operations
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Environment specific constants.
    '
    ' Expected version of Microsoft Access - the returned value of property:
    '   ? Access.Application.Version
    Const AccessVersion = "16.0"
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Application specific constants.
    '
    ' Source filename.
    Const AppBaseName = "DMadresser"
    ' Extension name. Uncomment ONE extension name only.
    'Const AppExtensionName = "accdb"
    'Const AppExtensionName = "accde"
    Const AppExtensionName = "accdr"
    ' Optional suffix.
    Const AppNoColourSuffix = "NC"

    ' Local install folder names. Will be (sub)subfolders of %LocalAppData%.
    Const OrgSubfolderName = "DM"
    Const AppSubfolderName = "DM Administration"

    ' Shortcut name(s). Uncomment ONE folder name ONLY:
    Const ShortcutBaseName = "DM Adresser"
    'Const ShortcutBaseName = "DM Adresser Test"

    ' Title of the application when running. For TaskKill in subfunction KillTask.
    Const AppWindowTitle = "DM ADRESSER"
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Installation specific constants.

    ' Distribution folder names. Uncomment ONE folder name ONLY:
    Const AppTypeSubfolderName = "Files"
    'Const AppTypeSubfolderName = "Development"
    'Const AppTypeSubfolderName = "Operations"
    'Const AppTypeSubfolderName = "Test"

    ' Indicate if the script is for the normal version (0) or a no-colour version (1):
    Const NoColour = 0

    ' Force a close of an open application even if blocked by a modal message box.
    Const ForceClose = True
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Script.

    ' Windows folder constants.
    Const DESKTOP = &H10
    Const LOCALAPPDATA = &H1C
    ' Extension of a shortcut.
    Const ShortcutExtensionName = "lnk"

    ' Objects.
    Dim FileSystemObject
    Dim AppShell
    Dim DesktopFolder
    Dim LocalAppDataFolder
    Dim LocalFolder
    Dim RemoteFolder

    ' Variables.
    Dim LocalFolderName
    Dim RemoteFolderName
    Dim DesktopFolderName
    Dim LocalAppDataFolderName
    Dim LocalAppDataOrgFolderName
    Dim LocalAppDataOrgAppFolderName
    Dim AppName
    Dim AppExtension
    Dim AppSuffix
    Dim ShortcutName
    Dim AppLocalPath
    Dim AppRemotePath
    Dim ShortcutExtension
    Dim ShortcutLocalPath
    Dim ShortcutRemotePath
    Dim RegPath
    Dim RegKey
    Dim RegValue
    Dim Value


    ' Create the Shell object and the File System Object.
    Set FileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set AppShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    ' Build distribution folder name.
    RemoteFolderName = FileSystemObject.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

    ' Build filenames.
    If NoColour = 1 Then
        AppSuffix = AppNoColourSuffix
    Else
        AppSuffix = ""
    End If
    AppExtension = "." & AppExtensionName
    AppName = AppBaseName & AppSuffix & AppExtension
    ShortcutExtension = "." & ShortcutExtensionName
    ShortcutName = ShortcutBaseName & AppSuffix & ShortcutExtension

    ' Enable in-line error handling.
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Find user's Desktop and AppData\Local folder.
    Set DesktopFolder = AppShell.Namespace(DESKTOP)
    DesktopFolderName = DesktopFolder.Self.Path
    Set LocalAppDataFolder = AppShell.Namespace(LOCALAPPDATA)
    LocalAppDataFolderName = LocalAppDataFolder.Self.Path

    ' Uncomment to debug.
    'WScript.Echo "Desktop: " & DesktopFolderName & vbCrLf & "LocalAppData: " & LocalAppDataFolderName

    ' Dynamic parameters.
    LocalAppDataOrgFolderName = FileSystemObject.BuildPath(LocalAppDataFolderName, OrgSubfolderName)
    LocalAppDataOrgAppFolderName = FileSystemObject.BuildPath(LocalAppDataOrgFolderName, AppSubfolderName)
    LocalFolderName = FileSystemObject.BuildPath(LocalAppDataOrgAppFolderName, AppTypeSubfolderName)
    AppLocalPath = FileSystemObject.BuildPath(LocalFolderName, AppName)
    ShortcutLocalPath = FileSystemObject.BuildPath(DesktopFolderName, ShortcutName)

    ' Permanent parameters.
    AppRemotePath = FileSystemObject.BuildPath(RemoteFolderName, AppName)
    ShortcutRemotePath = FileSystemObject.BuildPath(FileSystemObject.BuildPath(RemoteFolderName, ".."), ShortcutName)

    ' Verify/create the local folders.
    If Not FileSystemObject.FolderExists(RemoteFolderName) Then
        Call ErrorHandler("No access to " & RemoteFolderName & ".")
    Else
        Set RemoteFolder = FileSystemObject.GetFolder(RemoteFolderName)
        ' If the local folder does not exist, create the folder.
        If Not FileSystemObject.FolderExists(LocalFolderName) Then
            If Not FileSystemObject.FolderExists(LocalAppDataOrgFolderName) Then
                Set LocalFolder = FileSystemObject.CreateFolder(LocalAppDataOrgFolderName)
                If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
                    Call ErrorHandler("Folder " & LocalAppDataOrgFolderName & " could not be created.")
                End If
            End If
            If Not FileSystemObject.FolderExists(LocalAppDataOrgAppFolderName) Then
                Set LocalFolder = FileSystemObject.CreateFolder(LocalAppDataOrgAppFolderName)
                If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
                    Call ErrorHandler("Folder " & LocalAppDataOrgAppFolderName & " could not be created.")
                End If
            End If
            If Not FileSystemObject.FolderExists(LocalFolderName) Then
                Set LocalFolder = FileSystemObject.CreateFolder(LocalFolderName)
                If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
                    Call ErrorHandler("Folder " & LocalFolderName & " could not be created.")
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Set LocalFolder = FileSystemObject.GetFolder(LocalFolderName)
    End If

    ' Copy the distribution file to the local folder and the shortcut to the Desktop.
    If Not FileSystemObject.FileExists(AppRemotePath) Then
        Call ErrorHandler("The application file:" & vbCrLf & AppRemotePath & vbCrLf & "could not be found.")
    Else
        ' First, close a running application - using the setting of constant ForceClose.
        Call KillTask(AppWindowTitle)
        ' Wait while TaskKill is running to close the instance of the application.
        Call AwaitProcess("taskkill.exe")

        ' Copy app to local folder.
        If FileSystemObject.FileExists(AppLocalPath) Then
            FileSystemObject.DeleteFile(AppLocalPath)
            If Not Err.Number = 0 Then
                If IsProcess("MSACCESS.EXE") Then
                    ' The application may be blocked for closing by a modal message box.
                    MsgBox "Cannot update or reinstall the application while it is running.", vbCritical + vbOkOnly, AppWindowTitle
                    WScript.Quit        
                Else
                    Call ErrorHandler("The application file:" & vbCrLf & AppName & vbCrLf & "can not be refreshed/updated. It may be in use.")
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If FileSystemObject.FileExists(AppLocalPath) Then
            Call ErrorHandler("The local application file:" & vbCrLf & AppLocalPath & vbCrLf & "could not be replaced.")
        Else
            FileSystemObject.CopyFile AppRemotePath, AppLocalPath
            If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
                Call ErrorHandler("Application could not be copied to " & LocalFolderName & ".")
            End If
        End If

        ' Uncomment to debug.
        'WScript.Echo "Shortcut remote: " & ShortcutRemotePath & vbCrLf & "Shortcut local: " & ShortcutLocalPath

        ' Copy shortcut.
        FileSystemObject.CopyFile ShortcutRemotePath, ShortcutLocalPath
        If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
            Call ErrorHandler("Shortcut could not be copied to your Desktop.")
        End If
    End If

    ' Write Registry entries for Microsoft Access security.
    RegKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & AccessVersion & "\Access\Security\"
    RegValue = "VBAWarnings"
    RegPath = RegKey & RegValue
    Value = 1
    Call WriteRegistry(RegPath, Value,"REG_DWORD")

    RegKey = RegKey & "Trusted Locations\LocationLocalAppData\"
    RegValue = "AllowSubfolders"
    RegPath = RegKey & RegValue
    Value = 1
    Call WriteRegistry(RegPath, Value, "REG_DWORD")

    RegValue = "Date"
    RegPath = RegKey & RegValue
    Value = Now
    Value = FormatDateTime(Value, vbShortDate) & " " & FormatDateTime(Value, vbShortTime)
    Call WriteRegistry(RegPath, Value, "REG_SZ")

    RegValue = "Description"
    RegPath = RegKey & RegValue
    Value = "Local AppData"
    Call WriteRegistry(RegPath, Value, "REG_SZ")

    RegValue = "Path"
    RegPath = RegKey & RegValue
    Value = LocalAppDataFolderName & "\"
    Call WriteRegistry(RegPath, Value, "REG_SZ")

    ' Launch the application.
    If FileSystemObject.FileExists(AppLocalPath) Then
        Call RunApp(AppLocalPath)
    Else
        Call ErrorHandler("The local application file:" & vbCrLf & AppLocalPath & vbCrLf & "could not be found.")
    End If

    Set RemoteFolder = Nothing
    Set LocalFolder = Nothing
    Set LocalAppDataFolder = Nothing
    Set DesktopFolder = Nothing
    Set AppShell = Nothing
    Set FileSystemObject = Nothing

    ' Exit.
    WScript.Quit

' Exit script.
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Supporting (sub)functions.

Sub RunApp(ByVal Filename)

    Const vbNormalFocus = 1
    Const WaitOnReturn = False

    Dim Shell
    Dim Command
    Dim WindowStyle

    ' Open as default foreground application.
    WindowStyle = vbNormalFocus

    Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Command = """" & Filename & """"
    Shell.Run Command, WindowStyle, WaitOnReturn

    Set Shell = Nothing

End Sub


Sub KillTask(ByVal WindowTitle)

    Const vbMinimizedNoFocus = 7
    Const WaitOnReturn = False
    Const ForcedCloseOn = "/F"
    Const ForcedCloseOff = ""

    Dim Shell
    Dim Command
    Dim WindowStyle
    Dim CloseStyle

    ' Run silently.
    WindowStyle = vbMinimizedNoFocus

    Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    If ForceClose = True Then
        CloseStyle = ForcedCloseOn
    Else
        CloseStyle = ForcedCloseOff
    End If
    Command = "TaskKill.exe /FI ""WINDOWTITLE eq " & WindowTitle & """ " & CloseStyle
    Shell.Run Command, WindowStyle, WaitOnReturn

    Set Shell = Nothing

End Sub


Sub AwaitProcess(ByVal Process)

    Dim Service
    Dim Query
    Dim Processes
    Dim Count

    Set Service = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
    Query = "select * from win32_process where name = '" & Process & "'"

    Do
        Set Processes = Service.Execquery(Query)
        Count = Processes.Count
        If Count > 0 Then
            WScript.Sleep 300
        End If
    Loop Until Count = 0

    Set Processes = Nothing
    Set Service = Nothing

End Sub

Function IsProcess(ByVal Process)

    Dim Service
    Dim Query
    Dim Processes
    Dim Result

    Set Service = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
    Query = "select * from win32_process where name = '" & Process & "'"

    Set Processes = Service.Execquery(Query)
    If Processes.Count > 0 Then
        Result = True
    Else
        Result = False
    End If

    Set Processes = Nothing
    Set Service = Nothing

    IsProcess = Result

End Function


Sub WriteRegistry(ByVal RegPath, ByVal Value, ByVal RegType)
    ' RegType should be:
    '   "REG_SZ" for a string
    '   "REG_DWORD" for an integer
    '   "REG_BINARY" for a binary or boolean
    '   "REG_EXPAND_SZ" for an expandable string

    Dim Shell

    Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Call Shell.RegWrite(RegPath, Value, RegType)

    Set Shell = Nothing

End Sub


Sub ErrorHandler(Byval Message)

    Set RemoteFolder = Nothing
    Set LocalFolder = Nothing
    Set LocalAppDataFolder = Nothing
    Set DesktopFolder = Nothing
    Set AppShell = Nothing
    Set FileSystemObject = Nothing

    MsgBox Message, vbExclamation + vbOkOnly, ShortcutBaseName
    WScript.Quit

End Sub


' End script.
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```